# Creating a conditional iterative list

Tags: python, list

I have a list B=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] but it can be any length.

I am trying to iterate through all possible values I can place in B by iteration. When some condition C is met, I want to "reset" the element I just iterated and bump the next item up by 1. Sort of like binary:

000 becomes 001 but then when we increase to 002, condition C is met so we drop it to 0 and increment the next column: 002 becomes 010, etc.

Sorry if I explained that poorly.

So B might go from

```
B=[0,0,0,0,1,2,5]
to
B=[0,0,0,0,1,2,6]
to
B=[0,0,0,0,1,2,7]
```

and so forth.

But when condition C is met, I want to reset in this way:

```
B=[0,0,0,0,1,2,96]
...attempt to increment
B=[0,0,0,0,1,2,97]
...attempt to increment
Condition C met
B=[0,0,0,0,1,3,0]
```

And be able to do this until I eventually hit condition C on the far left element (equivalent to hitting 1111111 and being unable to increase it any more).

For the sake of easier coding let's say condition C = the sum of all the numbers exceeds 100.

My attempt (as requested by agf):

```
B=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
lenB=len(B)

while sum(B)<=100: #I think I have to somehow account for having tried incrementing the far left instead
    B[lenB-1]+=1 #increment last value in B
    while sum(B)>100: #if the sum is greater than 100
        B[lenB-1]=0 #reset the far right element
        B[lenB-2]+=1 #increment the next element
        #but this is wrong because it needs to perform this check again and again
        #for every column, while also checking if B[len-1] or B[len-2] even exists
```

EDIT: My Condition C in reality is *MUCH* more complex than simply checking if Sum(B)>100. I'm just using this as a dummy condition because I can simply replace "if sum(B)>100" with my more complex conditional function.

Comment: What have you tried? Please tell us _specifically_ what part you can't solve, and show us your attempt. We're not here to write your code for you.

Comment: I don't know how to properly loop through the process and keep track of where I am and how I know to increment things. Because I think I have to account for situations where I need to reset multiple things at once like how you could be at 0111111 and "reset" to 1000000.

Comment: @agf I added my attempt above as requested

Comment: @jcfollower No it is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
B=[0,1,0]

def check(ll,callback):
    """
    This function only works if you 
    increment the last element in the list.
    All other incrementing is done in this function.
    """
    for idx in reversed(range(len(ll))):
        if(callback(ll)):
            ll[idx]=0
            ll[idx-1]+=1
        else:
            break  #this index wasn't updated, so the next one won't be either.

    #a check to see if every element is 1
    return all(map(lambda x: x==1,ll))

def checksum(ll):
    return True if sum(ll)>100 else False

count=0
while True:
    count+=1
    B[-1]+=1
    if(check(B,checksum)): break
    print B

print B   # [1,1,1]
print count
```

Even for this example, we run through over 5000 iterations before [1,1,1]

**EDIT**

Added a simple `break` statement as it is only necessary to check the list as long as it changed during the last iteration.

Comment: Yes it is -- I think I'd just have to wrap up the check and B[-1]+=1 part inside a loop. How would I be able to place a final end condition when I try to update the far left column and cannot do so?

Comment: Presumably, the last element to be possibly updated is the first element in the list, so after the for loop, you can check to see if your end condition is met and return some value from check.

Comment: I changed my mind, now that he clarified his question. I think this is basically the correct approach.

Comment: I modified it to allow for stop-condition by adding "if idx==0: return 1" in check's if-statement.

Comment: Apparently I was modifying my answer while you accepted it...but anyway, I've added a simple "stop" condition to check if every element is 1 in the list -- that may not be what you want, but it's kind of cool to see the output...

Comment: @AOAOne This should work (except for the stop condition), but the logic isn't quite correct. You're re-checking the callback even if you've not changed anything in the list. Instead, you should only be checking the callback after incrementing a digit. The "stop condition" is if the callback is still True after you've reset the next-to-leftmost digit and incremented the leftmost digit, since that would require you to increment a digit past the left end of the list. See my answer.

Comment: @agf  Yes, the logic isn't quite correct.  Originally I thought the OP wanted to check the list based on individual items in the list (hence the leftover `item=ll[idx]` also.)

Comment: Edited to address @agf's comment.  As far as the stop condition, I'm a little unclear how the OP wants to determine when he's done adding things into the list, so agf may be correct about that...

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I appear to have created a solution to a different, more complex problem. Here is my solution to the problem as clarified by agf in the comments:

```
def uphill(initial=None):
    """Yields a tuple of integers. On each iteration, add one to the last column
    . If True is sent then reset the column, and begin iterating the previous
    column, until the first column is matched."""
    b = initial
    column = len(initial)-1
    while True:
        if (yield tuple(b)):
            b[column] = 0
            if column > 0:
                column -= 1
                b[column] += 1
            else:
                yield None
                raise StopIteration
            yield None
        else:
            b[column] += 1

gen = uphill([1, 2, 0])
for b in gen:
    print(b)
    if sum(b) >= 4:
        gen.send(True)
```

Giving us:

```
(1, 2, 0)
(1, 2, 1)
(1, 3, 0)
(2, 0, 0)
(3, 0, 0)
(4, 0, 0)
```

---

## Old solution:

We can create a very elegant solution with generators and the little-known `generator.send()`:

```
def waterfall(columns):
    """Yields a tuple of integers. On each iteration, adds one to the last list
    item. The consumer can send column numbers to the waterfall during iteration
     - when this is done, the specified column is reset to 0 and the previous 
    column is incremented. When the first column is reset, the iterator ends."""
    b = [0]*columns
    while True:
        reset = (yield tuple(b))
        if not reset == None:
            while not reset == None:
                b[reset] = 0
                if reset > 0:
                    b[reset-1] +=1
                else:
                    yield None
                    raise StopIteration
                reset = (yield None)
        else:
            b[-1] += 1

gen = waterfall(3)
for b in gen:
    print(b)
    if b[2] >= 3:
        gen.send(2)
    if b[1] >= 2:
        gen.send(1)
    if b[0] >= 1:
        gen.send(0)
```

Which gives us:

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 3)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 1, 3)
(0, 2, 0)
(1, 0, 0)
```

You could happily change these conditions to anything. You simply send the generator the index of the column you wish to reset (which automatically increments the one above it by one) when your condition of choice is met. When the last column is reset, it finishes the generator.

It's also worth noting you can use `gen.close()` to stop it at any time, without needing to reach the final column. (`gen.send(0)` is the same as `gen.close()`).

An example with a different condition:

```
gen = waterfall(2)
for b in gen:
    print(b)
    if sum(b) >= 3:
        gen.send(1)
    if b[0] >= 3:
        gen.send(0)
```

Giving us:

```
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(0, 3)
(1, 0)
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 0)
(2, 1)
(3, 0)
```

Comment: @JakobBowyer They allow you to do some cool stuff. It also makes the syntax of the main loop that much better - you can focus on what is important rather than all the flow control.

Comment: How would you encapsulate this for the general case? Like in my or hexaparrot's answer? I'm not sure how useful this is if you have to special-case the resetting -- it's supposed to be able to tell which digit to reset, you just tell it whether to reset or not.

Comment: @agf The value to give to ``send()`` is the column to reset. Hence you can use any condition you like to reset any column.

Comment: @Lattyware Yes, I understand that. But past of the algorithm he asked for was for it to automatically roll over values. Yours doesn't do that, you have to manually roll over each digit and make sure you're doing it right. So you need another layer that correctly decides which columns to roll over. All you should need provided is the condition on which a roll over should occur, not which column to roll over.

Comment: @agf How is my code meant to know what condition maps to what column?

Comment: Which column you changes depends only on which digit you incremented last, not on what the condition is. Look at `sum(lst) == 4`. If you have `[1, 2, 0]`, then you increment to `[1, 2, 1]`, the condition is met, and you reset the digit you just incremented, and increment the next digit. Now you have `[1, 3, 0]`. The condition is still met, so you reset the digit you just incremented, and increment the next digit. Now you have `[2, 0, 0]`. The condition isn't met so you move back to the last item in the list. See what I mean? You can determine the index independent of what the condition is.

Comment: @agf I see, I had the wrong end of the stick and was solving another problem. I have updated with a solution that I believe matches your description.

Answer (score 1):

```
def increment(box, condition):
    # last index in the list
    maxindex = index = len(box) - 1
    while True:
        # so you can see it's correct
        print box
        # increment the last digit
        box[-1] += 1
        # while the overflow condition is True
        while condition(box):
            # reset the current digit
            box[index] = 0
            # and move to the next index left
            index -= 1
            # if we're past the end of the list
            if index < 0:
                # stop
                return
            # increment the current digit
            box[index] += 1
        # back to the rightmost digit
        index = maxindex

increment([0] * 3, lambda box: sum(box) > 4)
```

Comment: I think I need to edit my question -- Condition C is not digit-specific. It actually encapsulates all elements of B but I only chose "sum(B)>100" because it is simple and easy. Is it easier if I mention that Condition C is arbitrary?

Comment: @AOAOne That doesn't really matter. Instead of checking `if box[index] == maxval` just check whatever your condition is. The rest of the logic is the same.

Comment: Tried it out and it seems to repeat values and go beyond the bounds of my reset condition. For instance if you place if sum(box)>10, it'll display things like [0,0,11] and repeat a few things.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a list comprehension and [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/functions.html#range) (using small values here to stop the output being very large):

```
>>> [(a, b, c) for a in range(2) for b in range(4) for c in range(3)]
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (0, 3, 0), (0, 3, 1), (0, 3, 2), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 3, 0), (1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2)]
```

Note that if you want to loop over it, rather than generating a big list at the beginning, using a generator expression only creates items as needed:

```
for a, b, c in ((a, b, c) for a in range(2) for b in range(4) for c in range(3)):
    ...
```

And note that in Python 2.x, here you would want to use [`xrange()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange) rather than `range` to get generators rather than lists.

Comment: This will only work if the conditions are specific to the digits. E.g. `B <= 5`. It won't work for e.g. `sum(list) >= 100` as in the example.

Comment: @agf He's said it's not for homework, so there is no reason to do so.

Comment: My condition C is actually much more complex than sum(B)>100 but it's a dummy condition that is easy to check for the sake of asking this question. My problem lies with incrementing/resetting the list properly.

Comment: @cmh Not true, you could make your own generator to do different operations if not on number sequences. I'll update with a more generic solution.

Comment: Oh I see. You're creating a generator for the universe of solutions and then filtering on that. Neat solution! However it could get inefficient for a very large universe but with a small subset that is valid.

Consider

`filter(lambda l: sum(l) < 100, (a,b) for a in range(large_num) for b in range(large_num))`

Comment: @agf: That's a shame. With arbitrary conditions it's a much more interesting problem!

Comment: @cmh I have posted my general answer as [a different answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10197465/722121), as this answer still stands as a simple solution to the simple case.

Answer (score 0):

**Compact but inefficient solution**

If your conditions are not digit specific, try using a solution similar to LattyWare, but with a filter to only provide the predicated results.

If you have a list of predicate functions mapping `(a, b, c)` to `bool`

```
for a, b, c in ((a, b, c) for a in range(2) for b in range(4) for c in range(3)):
    if all [p(a,b,c) for p in predicates]:
        yield a, b, c
```

Note that this becomes untenable if you can't put a reasonable inital bound on the individual digits (the search spaces becomes too large).

Comment: This isn't a good method. How do you know what size the ranges should be? Depending on the predicates, this could be _incredibly_ inefficient because the vast majority of the items won't be valid. With a digitwise incrementor, if you know you have to increment after a 5, you don't check 6, 7, 8, etc.

Comment: I agree that's it's potentially very inefficient (and said as much in my answer). It is, however, elegant for the times when the ranges are small.

Comment: But if the predicate is very complicated / nondeterministic how do you know what the ranges should be? For `sum`, the max for each values is the `sum`, but what about for something more complex?

Comment: You may not. I'm not arguing that's it's a good (read efficient) solution in all cases. However it does solve the problem and present a nice example of python's expressiveness. I did attach two health warnings to this answer!

Comment: For any solution to work the ranges must finite and bounded. My solution will work but slower.

`random.rand() < 0.0001` won't produce deterministic results so it renders the question posed meaningless.

Comment: And I have consistently agreed with you on that point. Namely that this only works if you know your bounds. My corollary was that you don't need to explicitly know the bounds (e.g. int_max) as long as your "space" can be considered bounded (e.g. int_max) and therefore finite.

Comment: Ok, then we're not really disagreeing about that. I just don't see this as a _practical_ solution, so therefore not a solution at all.

Comment: That's a fair viewpoint to take. I was going to hack a global reset into my range function to make it efficient but LattyWare did something much more pretty.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to address your incrementing issue as you're expecting:

```
b=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,7]

def incr(arr, condition, pred):
   arr[-1] += 1
   element = -1
   while condition(arr) > pred:

      if arr[element]:
         arr[element] = 0
         arr[element-1] += 1
      else:
         element -= 1
      if abs(element) == len(arr):
         break
   return arr

print b
for i in xrange(0,10):
   b = incr(b, sum, 15)
   print b
```

A function accepts the list and a functional condition (e.g., sum) and the point where the increment should carry over.

Thus it returns a result like this for the example sum (15):

```
>>> 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 7]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 8]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 9]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 10]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 11]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 12]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 13]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 14]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2]
```